# cohomology ring structure $H^\ast(\mathbb{R}P^3 \times \mathbb{R}P^3; \mathbb{Z}/p)$ for prime $p$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to determine the ring structure of $H^\ast(\mathbb{R}P^3 \times \mathbb{R}P^3; \mathbb{Z}/p)$ for prime $p$.

If $p$ is an odd prime, then each $H^k(\mathbb{R}P^3; \mathbb{Z}/p)$ is zero (by looking at the cellular chain complex). So I'm really looking at the case $p=2$. Then I have $H^k(\mathbb{R}P^3;\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/2$ when $k=0,1,2,3$ and zero otherwise.

I know the Kunneth Formula for Cohomology: $H^k(X \times Y) \cong \bigoplus\limits_{p+q=n} H^p(X) \otimes H^q(Y) \bigoplus\limits_{p+q=n+1} \mbox{Tor}(H^p(X),H^q(Y))$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}/2 \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2 \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, Tor$(\mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/2$, and Tor$(0, \mathbb{Z}/2)=0$,

I get $H^0(\mathbb{R}P^3 \times \mathbb{R}P^3; \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$,
$H^1(\mathbb{R}P^3 \times \mathbb{R}P^3; \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2)^5$ where two copies come from tensor product of cohomology groups and 3 copies come from Tor, $H^2(\mathbb{R}P^3 \times \mathbb{R}P^3; \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2)^7$ where 4 copies come from the product of cohomology groups an 3 copies come from Tor. I can keep doing this until the dimension of the largest cell, 9, but **my main question is what can I do next to actually determine the ring structure?**

In addition to that, this method seems pretty tedious. **Is there a better route I can take toward calculating the cohomology groups of a direct product?**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: My rusty mathematics tells me that $H^*(X\times Y; \mathbb{F})\cong H^*(X; \mathbb{F})\otimes H^*(Y; \mathbb{F})$ when $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. See, e.g. [Hatcher](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), Theorem 3.15.

Comment: A few issues:  1. when $p$ is an odd prime $H^3(\mathbb{R}P^3;\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p$, not $0$.  2.  $H^2(\mathbb{R}P^3\times \mathbb{R}P^3;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is isomorphic to only 3 copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2$.  The point is that the Kunneth formula you just stated is for $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, not $\mathbb{Z}/p$ coefficients.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks for pointing out my mistake for odd $p$. For point #2, what is the Kunneth formula for $\mathbb{Z}/p$ coefficients? I thought this formula worked for any coefficient group

Comment: As @QuangHoang points out, when you use field coefficients, it has no $Tor$ piece.  In general, my homological algebra is bad, so if I had to compute $H^\ast(X\times Y; R)$ for some weird commutative ring $R$, I'd probably compute $H^\ast(X\times Y; \mathbb{Z})$ first using Kunneth, and then compute $H^\ast(X\times Y; R)$ using universal coefficients.  However, there is likely a better way.

Comment: @Zebramuscles1234 The Kunneth formula you quoted is correct in general. In this case, $\mathbb Z/p$ is a field, so every $\mathbb Z/p$-module is free. Therefore, $Tor$ terms are always $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I want to add this as a remark

Since you are working over field coefficient, one can apply Kunneth Formula without any Tor term. Hence we have:

$H^{*}(\mathbb{RP}^{3}\times\mathbb{RP}^{3};\mathbb{Z}/p)\cong H^{*}(\mathbb{RP}^{3};\mathbb{Z}/p)\otimes H^{*}(\mathbb{RP}^{3};\mathbb{Z}/p)$.

Inorder to calculate the cohomology $H^{*}(\mathbb{RP}^{3};\mathbb{Z}/p)$ use the restriction map $q:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/p$.